# How do I remove ”File and Code Templates” in JetBrains GoLand?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

It's gray and I can't click it.

[image]

Comment: 1) Seems to me that it's a bundled one (at very least it uses standard name). Why do you need to remove it? 2) If you add another template, can you select and remove this one then?

Comment: 1) I do use it, but I'm confused why it can't be deleted. 2) It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug on GoLand side. Please see and follow [GO-13546](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-13546).

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really a strange bug.